# How to detect that entire binded ViewModel has changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, model-binding

I have a simple viewmodel class which contains three properties.

```
public class ColorViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int red;
    public int Red
    {
        get { return red; }
        set
        {
            if (red != value)
            {
                red = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Red");
            }
        }
    }

    private int green;
    public int Green
    {
        get { return green; }
        set
        {
            if (green != value)
            {
                green = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Green");
            }
        }
    }

    private int blue;
    public int Blue
    {
        get { return blue; }
        set
        {
            if (blue!= value)
            {
               blue = value;
               RaisePropertyChanged("Blue");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Now I want to pass entire model to a given **converter** in order to create a color for RGB values.

```
<Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="120" Width="120"
    Fill="{Binding Model, Converter={StaticResource intToBrushValueConverter}}"/>
```

where `Model` is one instance of my `ColorViewModel`.

The problem is that `intToBrushValueConverter` converter is trigger only once, when the program started. With the other words, the converter is not fired when `Model` is changed.

Then when one property of `ColorViewModel` is changed, the `PropertyChanged` is working, but `initToBrushValueConverter` converter it's not hitting.

There is one method to fix that ?

I'm searching for one solution without using `MultiBinding` or `CommandParameter`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can see that you have `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the `ColorViewModel` properties, what about the `Model` property itself? Since converters only trigger when the binding property is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook property changed event to parent viewmodel and in fire property changed event whenever property changes on Color property.

```
public class ParentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ColorViewModel color;
    public ColorViewModel Color
    {
        get { return color; }
        set
        {
            if (color != value)
            {
                if (color != null)
                    color.PropertyChanged -= this.ChildPropertyChanged;

                color = value;

                if (color != null)
                    color.PropertyChanged += this.ChildPropertyChanged;

                RaisePropertyChanged("Color");
            }
        }
    }

    private void ChildPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Color == sender)
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged("Color");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Full working solution below.

MainWindows.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Random random = new Random();
        private ParentViewModel model;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;
            this.model = new ParentViewModel();
            this.model.Color = new ColorViewModel();
        }

        public ParentViewModel Model
        {
            get { return model; }
            set
            {
                model = value;
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.model.Color.Blue = (byte)random.Next(0, 255);
            this.model.Color.Green = (byte)random.Next(0, 255);
            this.model.Color.Red = (byte)random.Next(0, 255);
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:IntToBrushConverter x:Key="intToBrushConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="120" Width="120" Fill="{Binding Model.Color, Converter={StaticResource intToBrushConverter}, FallbackValue=Black}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Click me!" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

IntToBrushConverter.cs

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class IntToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if(value is ColorViewModel)
            {
                var color = value as ColorViewModel;
                return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(color.Red, color.Green, color.Blue));
            }


            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

ParentViewModel.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class ParentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ColorViewModel color;
        public ColorViewModel Color
        {
            get { return color; }
            set
            {
                if (color != value)
                {
                    if (color != null)
                        color.PropertyChanged -= this.ChildPropertyChanged;

                    color = value;

                    if (color != null)
                        color.PropertyChanged += this.ChildPropertyChanged;

                    RaisePropertyChanged("Color");
                }
            }
        }

        private void ChildPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Color == sender)
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged("Color");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

ColorViewModel.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class ColorViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private byte red;
        public byte Red
        {
            get { return red; }
            set
            {
                if (red != value)
                {
                    red = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Red");
                }
            }
        }

        private byte green;
        public byte Green
        {
            get { return green; }
            set
            {
                if (green != value)
                {
                    green = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Green");
                }
            }
        }

        private byte blue;
        public byte Blue
        {
            get { return blue; }
            set
            {
                if (blue != value)
                {
                    blue = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Blue");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

App.xaml and App.xaml.cs are standard as generated by template.

Output

[image: Initial window]

[image: Random color 1]

[image: Random color 2]

Hope it helps!

Comment: After this I have to use an instance of ParentViewModel, right ?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut Can you post class where your Model property is? I will update the answer.

Comment: It's just in `MainWindow`

Comment: Wait wait wait. What is the DataContext of Rectangle you are trying to use?

Comment: DataContext is a reference to `MainWindow`

Comment: Inside MainWindow I used a instance of ColorViewModel which I used it to XAML.

Comment: Okay. They. Yeah, create your ParentViewModel. Call it whatever it is more meaningful to you. MainVieModel? And try using the rest of the code.

Comment: It's not working. I updated my question with code from MainWindow.

Comment: Let me try. Will get back to you soon

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut Take a look at an update. Hope it helps

Comment: I will try tomorrow when i will arrive to office..but thanks for your effort. I'm sure that your answer must be working.

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut Let me know if anything else needs to be solved according to your problem. Have fun

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Rectangle listens only to `PropertyChanged` events for the `Model` and not for the three color properties.

Try raising an event for the `Model` itself using `RaisePropertyChanged("Model");` or `RaisePropertyChanged(null);`.

Comment: `RaisePropertyChanged("Model");` will do nothing as the sender is Model property instance and have no such a property. `RaisePropertyChanged(null);` will fire property changed for each and every property on ColorViewModel, but still it will not fire change on Color property, thus converter will not act.